# Get the last record of each user by eventid

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

From the following db,

```
   id      userid        eventid      created_at
    1         1            100      2010-01-01
    2         1            101      2010-02-01
    3         1            100      2010-03-01
    4         1            101      2010-04-01
    5         2            100      2010-05-01
    6         2            100      2010-06-01
```

I'm trying to get the latest activity of of each user based on eventid, with an output like this:

```
6         2            100      2010-06-01
4         1            101      2010-04-01
3         1            100      2010-03-01
```

Comment: orderBy('eventid','desc') ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `group by` and `aggregation`

```
select userid,envid,max(id) as id, max(created_at) as created_at
from tablename a
group by userid,envid
```

Comment: great! now I just need to convert it to laravel db query!

Comment: This assumes that ids and `created_at` increase together.  The OP does not specify that this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

Use **Rownumber**

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, eventid ORDER BY id DESC) as RId,
             t.*
      FROM Tablename t
     ) T
WHERE RId = 1 ;
```